# Why are JITted Python implementations still slow?

Tags: c#, java, python, performance, jit

I understand why interpretation overhead is expensive, but why are JITted Python implementations (Psyco and PyPy) still so much slower than other JITted languages like C# and Java?

Edit:  I also understand that everything is an object, dynamic typing is costly, etc.  However, for functions where types can be inferred, I'm not sure why this matters.

Comment: Show me a function for which the type can be inferred.

Comment: Have you tried Jython? This runs on the JVM and possibly benitis from it. (Though I suspect not ;)

Comment: @delnan, The JVM infers types based on usage and can optimise/inline some methods for up to two types and has a fall back if its not one of those types. e.g. Say you use a List.size() which has many possible implmentations but in reality you only use ArrayList which could be extended but it isn't so it can inline this method.  The same applies for Object in Java (but not as useful)

Comment: @Peter: I know Polymorphic inline caching (I even mentioned it a minute ago in a comment ^^). But that's propably not what dismcha is talking about.

Comment: @delnan, In java terminology, I wouldn't expect the performance to be much different unless you could infer a primtive type. (staticly infering the type against polymorphic inlining) The JVM doesn't do this so while it might be an improvement, I don't believe this is the reason the performance is different.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey Even on the JVM (Jython, JRuby, etc.) there is the added overhead of the dynamic types inherent in the language. Doesn't matter how fast you make a JVM method call. Something like [RPython](http://code.google.com/p/rpython/) could change that, but RPython is not Python :-)

Comment: @delnan - here's a function for which the type can be inferred -- fib n
   | n < 2   = 1
   = fib (n - 1) + fib (n - 2) -- The type is inferred as fib :: !Int -> Int

Comment: @igouy: This question is tagged about Python JITs, not about Haskell(?).

Comment: @delnan - You asked to be shown a function for which the type can be inferred. Done.

Comment: @igouy: Are we being pedantic today? OP claims there are *Python* functions for which type inference can eliminate the cost of dynamicness, everything-is-an-object, etc. and I asked for an example. Of a *Python* function. In case you couldn't tell, I know about Haskell and other languages with Hindley-Milner type inference. Inferring types in a Hindley-Milner-esque type system is 100% possible, but Python's type system is very different, so Hindley-Milner has no relevance here.

Comment: @delnan - "Faster than C: Static type inference with Starkiller (2004)" - http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=D36D474DA810BA630E6AEB85BBE4D19C?doi=10.1.1.95.3786&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: @igouy: Thanks for the link, interesting read. I stand corrected - I ignored whole-program analysis.

Answer (score 11):

The simplest possible answer is that PyPy is simply not yet as fast as hotspot and Psyco never will.

Writing a reasonable JIT is a long and tedious process and it took for example many years for hotspot to get where it is (with a lot of funding as well). The more complex and dynamic the language is, the longer it takes. On the bright side, we have good examples how JITs for dynamic languages can be very fast, take LuaJIT for one, which can beat C or JVM on many examples.

There are good news however: According to [speed center](http://speed.pypy.org/changes/?tre=100&rev=40170:c407c9dc5382&exe=1&env=tannit) PyPy got 27% faster on average in the past 100 revisions, so it'll happen eventually.

Comment: Nice to point out LUA, which is pretty darn fast. However, the last statement supposes that if you a lift a calf each day from the day it was born, you will be able to lift it when it is a full-grown cow/bull -- which is not correct.

Comment: That would be the way to go about lifting a bull anyway :-) What I didn't say is that we have a lot of plans and/or half-working branches that make stuff faster.

Answer (score 6):

People have already pointed out the technical details, so I'll add another factor: money.

In the last few years, Javascript VMs (Google's V8, Mozilla's Tracemonkey & Jaegermonkey, Apple's Nitro) have delivered a huge speed increase for another dynamic language. That's been driven in large part by Google's desire to make web apps more powerful. Python just doesn't have a big company standing to gain by making it 50x faster.

Oh, and the integration with C extensions like numpy means that speed is rarely critical for Python code, anyway.

Comment: But for me the whole point of Python is a nice, easy to work with language.  If I have to even touch C and mess with a bunch of tools to glue Python and C together to get decent performance, I'd rather just write the whole thing in D or C# or something.  (Unless someone else wrote the C extensions and they're trivial to get up and running, i.e. Numpy.)

Comment: Well actually google is trying to do something: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unladen_Swallow

Comment: @dsimcha: Well, in a lot of common situations, there are C extensions like numpy/scipy/PyQt around. But beyond that, if you need speed, you're right, Python isn't the tool to use. But a lot of programs are limited by the network/database/file/user rather than the CPU.

Comment: Also, Cython. A C guru can propably use it best, but it's still a welcome speed boost for code that needs to work wth a Python system but is somewhat CPU-intense.

Comment: @digEmAll: That was a couple of guys at Google, and they got moved on to higher priority projects. The SVN branch (py3k-jit) hasn't been updated in a few months. I hope something comes of it, but I'm not holding my breath.

Answer (score 5):

Python is a [dynamic language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming_language).

This means that much of the work that other static languages (like C# and Java) do at compile time, is done at runtime and this reduces performances.

**EDIT:**
Furthermore, JIT compiler for a dynamic language like python, can perform much less optimisations on the code because it can't do many assumptions due to the dynamicity of the code.

**e.g.**
Dynamic typing prevents assumptions about type of fields/variables/parameters... , thus any optimisation involving that is almost impossible.

**EDIT2:**
just a clarification:
when I say compile time, I mean also JIT compile time, because actually JIT is a compiler.
Applying this to my first sentence, yields that Python can perform much less work at JIT time than C# or Java...

Comment: But shouldn't it be inferring types for the function instances it JITs?

Comment: @dsimcha: It propably does, *as far as possible*. But for `def f(x): return f.func1() + f.func2()`, you can't generate optimized machine code that gets two function pointers from fixed positions in vtables, call these, and uses one CPU instruction to add them. It has to look both methods up, call them, call the result's `__add__` method, etc.

Comment: Just an example: In C# (or Java) a variable HAS a certain type and cannot change it during execution. In Python it can, then JIT cannot perform any optimization involving variable type infos, because actually at any moment a variable could have different types...

Comment: BTW, The Java compiler doesn't do significant optimisations at compile time, the JVM optimises in the JIT but it can make more assumptions than a more dynamic language.

Comment: @digEmAll: That's another problem, although it's not impossible to optimize there - it's just more work for the JIT (and its authors). JVMs can actually inline polymorphic (i.e. `virtual`) methods, savely, with an overhead as little as one or two instructions. As long as most method calls actually call the same method, this gives you the full boost of branch prediction. It's called [polymorphic inline caching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_caching#Polymorphic_inline_caching) and it's really nifty.

Comment: @delnan: that's really interesting :)

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: you're right, I've just added a clarification at the end ;)

Comment: It should be theoretically possible to do more than is done at present. It's just a matter of establishing appropriate proof conditions on the optimizer so it can know that converting a series of computations into their “equivalent” in low-level code is correct because the confounding details are not observable. But going from theory to practice is… especially challenging… (Well, to put it politely and understate it a bit.)

Comment: @Donal Fellows: yes, probably it could be possible to do more, but I think it would be still slower than well-written C# or Java. Like C# or Java, will be always slower copared to well written C++ or C programs. Unfortunately, "the lower the language level is the faster is on execution" is almost a law (even if JITers have really narrowed the gap)

Comment: @digEmAll: The C# and Java ecosystems (what's the right word for “language, compiler and runtime”?) have had masses of optimization effort applied, but they're slower for programmers to write programs in than dynamic languages. The degree to which dynamic languages can be optimized at runtime remains an open question; what has been done with Javascript shows that it's possible to go a long way, but nobody knows the limit. I *theorize* that it's possible over time to get to the same level as C# and Java with *some* dynamic language. Maybe not Python. Just don't know. Yet…

Answer (score 1):

A really good question. I can't give you a complete answer, but I think one of the reasons is the "everything is objects and an object could be anything" concept. In Java, if you try "1.getClass()", it won't work unless you box it first, either explicitly or implicitly. In Python, it works out of the box. But objects are definitely more heavyweight than primitive types, which Python just doesn't seem to have.

The "an object can be anything" part is even more important. If you write "someobject.somefield" in Java, it knows at compile time what exactly is "somefield" and generates code that accesses it directly. Well, there are probably some tricks to give better binary compatibility, but that's nothing like Python, where it actually performs some sort of dictionary look-up at run time to figure out what exactly is "somefield" at that particular moment, as fields can be added and deleted dynamically.

To put it short, Python is more powerful, but that power has its cost.

Comment: This is not correct. [Scala](http://scala-lang.org) has "everything is an object" (with some little lies, but much more so than Java -- there are no primitives or static classes/methods in Scala). Yet, Scala (with static typing) can still easily run within a factor of Java or better. The difference between Scala and Python, relevant to this conversation, is static typing vs. dynamic typing.

Comment: @pst, you took just a half of my answer. I wrote "everything is objects and an object could be anything". The "object could be anything" part refers to precisely what you're talking about.

Comment: @igouy, to some extent, I am. But I just can't imagine a language with capabilities like those running as fast as Java. I'd say that I am answering a kind of "why Python implementations can't be as fast as those of Java or C#" question instead of "why are they slow".

Answer (score 1):

You can't really compare dynamic languages to enterprise-level static languages. Sun spent **a lot** of money  optimizing the language, VM and JIT.  Microsoft also did a fair job with their VM.

It is more interesting to compare jit'ed dynamic languages. Is it something about JavaScript that let google make their V8 faster than both [PyPy](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u32/benchmark.php?test=all&lang=v8&lang2=pypy) and [ruby 1.9](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u32/benchmark.php?test=all&lang=v8&lang2=yarv) or it is just amount of money one invests?

Comment: Of course you can make that comparison! The "amount of money one invests" explanation is the same explanation you gave for the better performance of Java and .Net (Do you think money might buy talent?)

Comment: @igouy: Do I think money might buy talent? Yes I do. Money can concentrate more talented people around one project.

Comment: While this starts off correct, the term "enterprise-level" practically nullifies everything before it. An "enterprise Python" still wouldn't be as fast -- ever -- because it *has to do more work*.

Answer (score 0):

> I understand why interpretation
>   overhead is expensive...

Compare those Python implementations [to non-JIT **interpreted-mode Java**](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u32/benchmark.php?test=all&lang=javaxint&lang2=pypy) and think about your question again.

Answer (score 0):

The whole issue is not so clear anymore in 2014. Google's V8 JS engine does some pretty heavy stuff to optimize the hell out of js.

PyPy could be much faster if only enough money would be available. Python's execution speed mostly does not matter so nobody heavily invests in PyPy.

It's really not a technical issue anymore. Look at Java's InvokeDynamic instruction. Sure, those invocations cost more the first time they are called, but the JVM can do magic stuff once those invocations start to start up. That is: The JVM can do assumptions and can learn about the code while running it. If a method always returns an int, it's possible that this method always returns an int. In reality the JVM does much more.

In 2014 it's really not dynamic vs static in terms of performance. Sure C++ will always be the fastest tool around, but jitted dynamic languages are not "magnitudes" slower as they used to be a few years ago.

Wait a few more years, I bet static analysis is much stronger in 2016 or 2017. There are a few very interesting research projects running right now.

**In Theory:**
You can basically infer every type using static type analysis, you have to understand **what** the code is doing before it does it. That's not impossible.

**When** static analysis becomes more powerful, you really do not need a static type system anymore. All static type systems, even haskell's, limit the number of correct programs. So in essence: If you have an analyzer which can proof the correctness of a program by analyzing it is much more powerful as a static type system which only can act within boundaries. And concerning code re-usage: Nothing can beat dynamic typing.

There are a few who would say that dynamic typing is bad for large applications but **if** static analysis becomes more powerful, you would actually have the same or maybe much more proven correctness as a static type system could ever offer. Of course statically typed languages could also be statically analyzed, but than the static type system would be useless.

So in essence: Here are a lot of if's, i know. But 10 years ago people would have laughed if you would have told them that js becomes the so fast, that you could easily write heavy 3d opengl applications in it.

**Never underestimate the future.**